# import csv in mysql db using ajax and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv

i was working on a mini project that imports csv file to the database through ajax and it's working fine.

here are my files

```
<?php
// creating database connection , executing queries and storing results
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "dbname" );
$query = "SELECT * FROM csv ORDER BY id desc ";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Marks Statistics</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<div class="container", style="width: 1000px;">
<h3 align="center">CSV DATABASE</h3><br/>
<!-- creating upload form -->

<form id="upload_csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Upload More Files</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" name="marks_file" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" >
        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="upload"  class="btn btn-info">
    </div>
    <div style= "clear:both"></div>
</form>
<br/><br/><br/>
    <!-- HTML table to display contents of the csv file -->
   <div class="table-responsive" id="marks_table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width="25%" >name</th>
            <th width="15%" >Physics</th>
            <th width="15%" >Maths</th>
            <th width="15%" >Chemistry</th>
            <th width="15%" >Biology</th>
            <th width="15%" >SST</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        ?>
        <!-- append row data into table -->
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Physics"]; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Maths"]; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Chemistry"]; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Biology"]; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["SST"]; ?> </td>
       <?php
        }
        ?>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#upload_csv').on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //form will not submitted
            $.ajax({
                 url:"export.php",
                 method:"POST",
                 data:new FormData(this),
                 contentType:false,          // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                 cache:false,                // To unable request pages to be cached
                 processData:false,          // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                 success: function(data){
                      if(data=='errorx')
                      {
                           alert("Invalid File");
                      }
                      else if(data == "errory")
                      {
                           alert("Please Select File");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                           $('#marks_table').html(data);
                      }
                 }
            })
       });  
  });
 </script>
```

And

```
 //export.php
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES["marks_file"]["name"]))
{
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
  $output = '';
  $allowed_ext = array("csv");
  $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["marks_file"]["name"]));
  if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))
  {
       $file_data = fopen($_FILES["marks_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
       fgetcsv($file_data);
       while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))
       {
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[0]);
            $Physics = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[1]);
            $Maths = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[2]);
            $Chemistry = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[3]);
            $Biology = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[4]);
            $SST = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[5]);
            $query = "
            INSERT INTO csv
                 (name, Physics, Maths, Chemistry, Biology, SST)
                 VALUES ('$name', '$Physics', '$Maths', '$Chemistry', '$Biology' , '$SST')
            ";
            mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       }
       $select = "SELECT * FROM csv ORDER BY id DESC";
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
       $output .= '
       <table class="table table-bordered">
           <tr>
               <th width="25%" >name</th>
               <th width="15%" >Physics</th>
               <th width="15%" >Maths</th>
               <th width="15%" >Chemistry</th>
               <th width="15%" >Biology</th>
               <th width="15%" >SST</th>
           </tr>
       ';
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
            $output .= '
                 <tr>
                      <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["Physics"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["Maths"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["Chemistry"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["Biology"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["SST"].'</td>
                 </tr>
            ';
       }
       $output .= '</table>';
       echo $output;
  }
  else
  {
       echo 'errorx';
  }
 }
  else
{
     echo "errory";
}
 ?>
```

however the imported csv files inserts null values in the tables
because the format of all csv files assigned to me are in the exact same format:

```
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,Fields,Physics~75,Maths~50,Chemistry~65,Bio~85,SST~100
,,,Name1,10,25,35,42,62
,,,Name2,80,45,45,45,25
,,,Name3,63,25,63,36,36
,,,Name4,82,36,75,48,42
,,,Name5,45,45,78,25,24
,,,Name6,36,36,15,75,36
,,,Name7,99,45,24,24,45
,,,Name8,45,85,85,85,96
```

i've tried multiple escape functions but none works, and it gets difficult to remove the fields line also.

Comment: So use the php continue staetment when Name is empty or equal to `Fields`?

Comment: Id fix this `VALUES ('$name', '$Physics',` SQLInjection issue

Comment: @danblack the ajax call breaks and nothing happens when i use continue;

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix sure mate, i'll fix it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this:

> csv files inserts null values in the tables
>   ,,,,,,,,
>   ,,,,,,,,

Check empty Like this (after filtering the array):

```
while($row = fgetcsv($file_data)) //['','','','','']
{
   if(empty(array_filter($row))) continue; //[] after array_filter
   ///...
}
```

For the `Fields` one you do essentially the same thing, except in the condition look for something like

```
while($row = fgetcsv($file_data)) //['','','','','']
{
   if(empty(array_filter($row)) || $row[3]=='Fields') continue; //[] after array_filter
   ///...
}
```

You can just look for `empty($row[3])` but that is only telling you that column is empty, not the whole row.

**UPDATE**

> I figured it out , it was a silly indexing error in my code considering the type of csv files i have.

If you want Associate arrays, with the keys from the header it can be very easy to do: If the headers are correct and the rows have the **correct number** of columns, and the names of the headers are **unique**:

```
   $headers = fgetcsv($file_data);   //['header1','header2']
   while($data = fgetcsv($file_data)) //['data1','data2']
   {
       $row = array_combine($headers,$data); //['header1'=>'data1','header2'=>'data2']
```

Array combine **Must** have the same number of keys as values to work (both arrays must be the same length).  In a typical CSV this "should" always be the case, in my experience it's not. However, when it's not that row is suspect to having it's data shifted to the wrong columns (under normal circumstances, without array combine).  So you have to ask yourself if your ok with that.

Anyway hope it helps.

Comment: i've tried this but then whenever i use continue; either it gives ma syntax error or the ajax call breaks and nothing happens

Comment: @zetastreak - there was a missing `)` sorry...  basic syntax error `if(empty(array_filter($row)) continue;` vs `if(empty(array_filter($row))) continue;`

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix yea that's a better way of doing it. many thanks :)

Comment: I do tones of stuff with CSV, it's possible (but tricky) to remap the headers too, doing it this way.  For example we have client set settings where they can change our file headers from `name` to ... `fullname` for example.  But in my code it's always `name` because I map them to that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , it was a silly indexing error in my code considering the type of csv files i have.
i added

```
if ($row[3]=='Fields' || $row[3]=='') continue;
```

and it worked.